# Onsubmit validate change background requried fields?

Tags: javascript, validation, onsubmit

Anyone know of a good tutorial/method of using Javascript to, onSubmit, change the background color of all empty fields with `class="required"` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick, but it's difficult to know exactly what you're looking for without you posting more details:

```
document.getElementById("myForm").onsubmit = function() {
    var fields = this.getElementsByClassName("required"),
        sendForm = true;
    for(var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
        if(!fields[i].value) {
            fields[i].style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000";
            sendForm = false;
        }
        else {
            //Else block added due to comments about returning colour to normal
            fields[i].style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
        }
    }
    if(!sendForm) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This attaches a listener to the `onsubmit` event of the form with `id` "myForm". It then gets all elements within that form with a class of "required" (note that `getElementsByClassName` is not supported in older versions of IE, so you may want to look into alternatives there), loops through that collection, checks the value of each, and changes the background colour if it finds any empty ones. If there are any empty ones, it prevents the form from being submitted.

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/cpG2r/7/).

Comment: Looks like an excellent script exactly what i wanted but for some reason im getting an error `Error: document.getElementById("formID") is null` (the id of my form is formID )

Comment: +1 for non jQuery solution like he asked for.  Just add some code to clear required classes for a 'second submit' scenario.

Comment: Perhaps the DOM is not ready when your code is running. Wrap my example in an `onload` function: `window.onload = function() { ...code here... }`

Comment: That did it, now I need to figure out how to do what @DefyGravity said; resubmit after the validation (the fields that get filled out go back to normal bg color)

Comment: @Jonah Katz - See my edit (I've added an `else` to the `if` statement).

Comment: @James Perfect! Great script!!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('form').submit(function () {
        $('input, textarea, select', this).foreach(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                $(this).addClass('required');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: There is no mention of jQuery in the question, so why give a jQuery answer?

Comment: Because its so pretty, and clean.

Comment: Yes, but as there's no mention of it, maybe it can't be used. In any case, it doesn't do what the OP asked for - "change the background of color of all empty fields with `class="required"`" - you are adding the class "required" to all empty elements.

Comment: @Jay looks nice but james is right, i prefer to not use jquery.

Answer (score 0):

I quickly became a fan of jQuery.   The documentation is amazing.

http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery

if You decide to give the library a try, then here is your code:

```
//on DOM ready event
$(document).ready(
  // register a 'submit' event for your form
  $("#formId").submit(function(event){
   // clear the required fields if this is the second time the user is submitting the form
   $('.required', this).removeClass("required");
   // snag every field of type 'input'.
// filter them, keeping inputs with a '' value
// add the class 'required' to the blank inputs.
   $('input', this).filter( function( index ){
       var keepMe = false;
       if(this.val() == ''){
         keepMe = true;
       }
       return keepMe;
     }).addClass("required");
   if($(".required", this).length > 0){
     event.preventDefault();
   }
  });
);
```

Comment: jQuery will work across browsers, and quickly lets me get out of the front end UI and back to the code I like to write.  It is an excellent library to pick up imho.