# onSubmit validation changing label style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm trying to get this form to change label color after submission if the field is empty and then return back to normal when the field is filled in.

It's behaviour would be something similar to:
[Onsubmit validate change background requried fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984480/onsubmit-validate-change-background-requried-fields)

Except I can't figure out how to link the inputs to the labels. I'm using the jsFiddle from the link above at:

http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/cpG2r/7/

```
window.onload = function() {
document.getElementById("myForm").onsubmit = function() {
  var fields = this.getElementsByClassName("required"),
      sendForm = true;
  for(var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
    if(!fields[i].value) {
      fields[i].style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000";
      sendForm = false;
    }
    else {
      fields[i].style.backgroundColor = "#fff";      
    }
  }
  if(!sendForm) {
    return false;
  }
}
}
```

My JavaScript isn't so good. Please help!

Comment: what you mean by 'how to link the inputs to the labels' ??

Comment: As in I need the script to see the inputs as empty, and then style the labels a different color. Then, once the inputs are filled, to remove the styling from the labels

Comment: Try something like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/n9e9v/2/

Comment: That's really close, but I need to label to turn back into white if the input has something in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Here is your [Working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/cpG2r/50/)`</>`

Answer (score 0):

> You should look around [Knockoutjs style binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/style-binding.html) with dom value.

Answer (score 0):

you could add `label` tags, like:

```
<form action="" id="myForm">
    <label for="field1">Required field:</label> <input type="text" name="field1" class="required" /><br />
    <label for="field2">Required field 2:</label> <input type="text" name="field2" class="required" />
    <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

And in js part

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("myForm").onsubmit = function() {
      var fields = this.getElementsByClassName("required"),
          sendForm = true;
      for(var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
          var lbl = document.getElementsByTagName("label")[i]; //get label
        if(!fields[i].value) {

            lbl.style.color = "red";
            console.log(lbl );
          fields[i].style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000";
          sendForm = false;
        }
        else {
            lbl.style.color = "black";
          fields[i].style.backgroundColor = "#fff";      
        }
      }
      if(!sendForm) {
        return false;
      }
    }
}
```

See : [updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cpG2r/48/)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<form action="" id="myForm">
    <label>Required field: </label><input type="text" class="required" /><br />
    <label>Required field 2: </label><input type="text" class="required" />
    <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

And

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("myForm").onsubmit = function() {
        var fields = this.getElementsByClassName("required"),
            sendForm = true;
        for(var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
            if(!fields[i].value) {
                fields[i].style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000";

                var prev = fields[i].previousSibling;
                while(!/label/i.test(prev.tagName)){
                    prev = prev.previousSibling;
                }

                prev.style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000";
                sendForm = false;
            }
            else {
                fields[i].style.backgroundColor = "#fff";      
            }
        }
        if(!sendForm) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/n9e9v/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **jquery validation Plugin** ... it has support for all types of validations as well as changing label colors & Can display suitable error messages

Answer (score 0):

> Here is very simple, smart yet effective way to doing this by using amazing knockout binding  here is working sample :[JsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/sb2BX/24/)

```
var viewModel = {
validation: ko.observable(function(){})
};
```